# NP-completeness of solving quadratic equations over $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: np-complete, np-hard

> Let $\chi$ be a degree 2 equation over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ of the form:
>   $$x_{i_1}x_{j_1} + x_{i_{2}}x_{j_1} + \cdots + x_{i_m}x_{j_m} + x_{k_1} + \cdots + x_{k_l} = b $$ for $ k_i \in \{1, \dots, n\}, b \in \{0,1\}$ for some $m, l \in \mathbb{N}$
>
> Prove that deciding whether a system of such equations has a solution is NP-complete.

---

So, we should to prove two things:

1) The problem $\in NP$

2) Another  NP-complete problem can be reduced to that problem.

I have no idea how to start. Please hint me. It is tempting to use $SAT$ problem, but, when I am trying to convert that problem I got stuck:
How to get $1$ (the truth value)?

Comment: See also https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/77985/755 for a related situation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can express the constraint $x \lor y = z$ (where $\lor$ is the OR operator) as the equation $(1-x)(1-y) = (1-z)$, that is, $xy+x+y+z=0$. Using this primitive you can express SAT, showing that your problem is NP-hard. Showing that it is in NP is easier.

Comment: thanks. But, I cannot understand why do you use $z$ in your equation. You have: $xy+x+y+z=0$. $z$ is constant ($0$ or $1$). If you can use constant it is trivial to express $x \vee y$ using xor. But, I don't see that we can use constant.

Comment: Showing that it is NP is easy: Just nondeterministically guess every possible valuation and check whether is it solution. it (in polynomial time).

Comment: Well, you have to keep thinking.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You said you don't understand why what I wrote is useful. Others seems to have understood, so I suggest you keep thinking about it.

Comment: I see that I can express SAT. But, you used constant in you equation. I have doubes if I can so I am asking you to explain me it.

Comment: Constants are actually allowed in your formulation, so I don't quite understand the question.

Comment: I wasn't sure that constants are allowed (I don't know why exactly :)). So, ok. It is easy.